# HP Proliant DL380 G7 power calculation

Tags: hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

HP Proliant DL380 G7 in year of production has alternative PSU:

750W in "performance" configurations with 2 CPU

460W in "base" and "entry" with 1 CPU

"Power advisor" calculator is not accesible in 2017

My question is:

**Can 460W PSU work with 2 middle range CPU** (80W nominal power), limited number 
of 2,5' HDD, 24GB-64GB RAM  and no extra controllers?

EDIT: machine for internal projects, sometimes will be down, 24/7 is not required

Answer (score 4):

The ILO will tell you how much power is being used.

But if you need a reference, here's what current statistics look like on a system with the following specifications:

```
2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) X5680  @ 3.33GHz
64GB RAM
4 x 10k SAS disks
4 x SATA SSD
```

Output of hpasmcli:

```
hpasmcli> SHOW POWERMETER
Power Meter #1
    Power Reading  : 160

hpasmcli> SHOW POWERSUPPLY
Power supply #1
    Present  : Yes
    Redundant: Yes
    Condition: Ok
    Hotplug  : Supported
    Power    : 80 Watts
Power supply #2
    Present  : Yes
    Redundant: Yes
    Condition: Ok
    Hotplug  : Supported
    Power    : 45 Watts
```

Also see: [How do servers with redundant power supplies balance consumption?](https://serverfault.com/questions/659452/how-do-servers-with-redundant-power-supplies-balance-consumption/659549#659549)